# Gmail contact info on hover not working

Tags: gmail

The Gmail feature where in the inbox you can hover over the sender's name to reveal a contact pop-up with full address info no longer works on my Gmail account. Does anyone know how to restore that feature?

My browser is Firefox 35.01. I could try to update to the most current version but I know that the hover feature worked with my version in the past.

Comment: Seems to be working for me. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: It works sporadically for me, as well. Personally, I use the desktop (non-Metro) version of Chrome Beta on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I suggest updating your browser or using a different one. It's entirely possible that the JavaScript for this feature has some quirk that's no longer compatible with FF 35.x. (The current version is 42.x.) In any case, there's no setting in Gmail to turn this on or off, so it must be an issue with your browser or some other local setting.

Answer (score 2):

[Clear your browser cache and cookies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en).
Check from different browser too.

Might be clearing cache didn't solve problem for Firefox. Use Chrome or any other browser (See [Supported browsers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6557?hl=en)).